# Recursive method on array of a recursive type duplicates values

Tags: c#, recursion, recursive-type

I'm messing around with recursive types to get used to them and learn, I've written the following class:

```
public class ParameterData
{
    public string[] Values { get; set; } = new string[0];
    public ParameterData[] NestedValues { get; set; } = new ParameterData[0];

    public bool IsNested { get => NestedValues.Length > 0; }
    public int Length { get => IsNested ? NestedValues.Length : Values.Length; }

    public dynamic this[int pos]
    {
        get
        {
            if (IsNested) return NestedValues[pos];
            else return Values[pos];
        }
        set
        {
            if (IsNested) NestedValues[pos] = value;
            else Values[pos] = value;
        }
    }

    public static implicit operator ParameterData[](ParameterData value)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, value))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("value");

        return value.NestedValues;
    }
}
```

This seems to work properly, according to the values shown in the debugger at least.

I've tried to use them, in an attempt to see where recursive types can be useful, but I've run into a problem, a "simple" loop runs 2 times over the nested items, I can't figure out if it's due to bad object design or bad loop coding. Could you give me some insight?

The code:

```
[TestMethod()]
public void LoadingWindowTest()
{
        ParameterData[] temp = new ParameterData[]{
            new ParameterData {Values=new string[]{ "Titulo" } },
            new ParameterData {Values=new string[]{ "Autor1" , "Autor2" } },
            new ParameterData {NestedValues=new ParameterData[]{
                new ParameterData {NestedValues=new ParameterData[]{
                    new ParameterData {Values = new string[]{"Hola"} },
                    new ParameterData {Values = new string[]{"Don", "Pepito"} }
                } },
                new ParameterData {Values = new string[]{"Outta Nest"} }
            } },
            new ParameterData {Values=new string[]{ "Last" } }
        };

        print(temp);
}

private void print(ParameterData[] data, int indent = 0)
{
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < data[i].Length; x++)
            {
                if (data[i][x] is string) Console.WriteLine("" + indent + data[i][x]);
                else print(data[i], indent + 1);
            }
        }
}
```

This is the output:

[image]

EDIT:
To clarify the issue: every line that starts with a value greater than 0 it's duplicated. Furthermore it's exponential, the lines are duplicated by 2^n where n it's the line's "level".

Comment: You get the duplicate output because you're iterating through the data with two loops. Don't do that. Let the recursive call do the work of dealing with the nested data. This is a great opportunity for you to learn how to use a debugger. Stepping through the code would've revealed to you right away what the problem is.

Comment: I will also strongly recommend that you get rid of your use of `dynamic`. The whole point of `dynamic` is to defer compilation until runtime, so that you can access a member of an object by name along, regardless of type. If you have to check the object's type explicitly (i.e. `is string`), then `dynamic` isn't helping. It would be better for the code to treat the `Values` and `NestedValues` properties explicitly anyway, rather than using an indexer.

Comment: I've litterally been using the debbuger as I said in the question itself, i don't see why I shouldn't use 2 loops tho. I'm essentially iterating a 2d array.  Could you please elaborate more on that?

Comment: _"I'm essentially iterating a 2d array"_ -- no you're not. You are iterating an N-dimensional array, where the recursive call to `print()` handles each additional dimension. As for using the debugger, your only statement about using it claims that the debugger shows you that the values are correct. That means either you're not _really_ using the debugger (i.e. to _step_ through the code rather than just inspecting data), or you aren't using the debugger correctly. Either way, you're missing the opportunity to learn how to use the debugger (correctly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Peter Duniho stated, my issue came from using 2 loops. The following code works as intended:

```
private void print(ParameterData[] data, int indent = 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            if (data[i].IsNested) print(data[i], indent + 1);
            else
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < data[i].Length; x++) Console.WriteLine("" + indent + data[i][x]);
            }
        }
    }
```

The source of my confusion was the fact that I implemented an indexer (for the sake of it) and that created the ilusion of working with a 2D array.

For anyone who might have a similar issue in the future:

- Don't use indexers(or anything really) where it's not needed
- An array of a type that contains an array of itself will be n-dimensional, no matter how it looks(this should be obvious, but here I am, having this issue).